# Segregation of multiple routes for pages and Apis with JWT using Express in Node.js

Tags: node.js, api, express, routes, jwt

Is there any way by which, I could segregate my multi Api(S) like

1. employees Api and its page redirection
2. customer Api and its page redirection etc !

Since currently what, I am doing is

```
var employees = require('./routes/employees');
   var customers = require('./routes/customers');
   app.use('/customers', isAuth, customers);
   app.use('/employees', isAuth, employees);
```

My JWT Part look like this

```
    function isAuth(req, res, next) {
        var token = req.body.token || req.param('token') || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    if (token != undefined) {

        // decode token
        if (token) {

            // verifies secret and checks exp
            jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.json({
                        success: false,
                        message: 'Failed to authenticate token.'
                    });
                } else {
                    // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                    req.decoded = decoded;
                    next();
                }
            });

        } else {

            // if there is no token
            // return an error
            return res.status(403).send({
                success: false,
                message: 'No token provided.'
            })

        }
    } else {
//check whether request is api or normal request !
        var string = req.url,
            substring = "api";
        if (string.indexOf(substring) !== -1) {
            res.status(403).send({
                success: false,
                message: 'No token provided.'
            })
        } else {
          //check whether request is authenticated or not !
            if (req.isAuthenticated())
                return next();
            /* res.status(401).json({authenticated: false});*/
            res.redirect('/login');
        }




    }



}
```

Any recommendations, improvements how to improve on below pointers with reference from above code snippets

1. separate routes of page redirection and apis much like in
   phoenixframework of  elixir.
2. jwt api routes authentications without current overcomplications of 
   aforementioned code snippets !.

here is code snippets of my elixir running under phoenix framework with simple api and page level segregation without jwt !

```
defmodule HelloPhoenix.Router do
  use HelloPhoenix.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", HelloPhoenix do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack
    get "/", PageController, :index
  end

  # Other scopes may use custom stacks.
   scope "/api", HelloPhoenix do
    pipe_through :api
   # resources "/users", UserController, except: [:new, :edit]
    resources "/users", UserController do
    post "/filterbackend", UserController,:filterbackend
    post "/bulkcreate", UserController,:bulkcreate
    post "/testpost", UserController,:testpost
    post "/filterRecordset", UserController,:filterRecordset
   end
   end
end
```